# Code coverage of Multiple files using Gcovr

Tags: c++, gcovr

i am new to gcovr. I have 3 files in my code namely main.cpp, math.cpp and math.hpp.I am compiled it with g++ using the following command

```
g++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -O0 main.cpp  math.cpp math.hpp -o math
```

my code is compiled and run successfully. when i run the following command for code coverage

```
 gcovr -r .
```

it produces the output like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.cpp                                       6       6   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          6       6   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It shows only the code coverage of main.cpp. I want to know the code coverage of other files too.How can i get it? Please help me if you can.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code 
main.cpp

```
#include "math.hpp"
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    Math m;
    m.Multiply(20, 50);
    m.Divide(40, 5);
}
```

Math.cpp

```
#include "math.hpp"

using namespace std;
int Math::Multiply(int Num1, int Num2){
    Mul= Num1 * Num2;
    std::cout << "Multiplication of "<<Num1<< " * " <<Num2<< " = "<< Mul<<endl;
    return Mul;
}

int Math::Divide(int Num1, int Num2){
    Div = Num1/Num2;
    std::cout << "Division of "<<Num1<< " / " <<Num2 <<" = "<< Div<<endl;
    return Div;
}
```

math.hpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include<iostream>
class Math
{
  int Num1;
  int Num2;
  int Fact, Mul, Div, Num, i;

public:
  int Multiply(int Num1,int Num2);
  int Divide(int Num1, int Num2);
};
```

When ran the command gcovr -v -r . is given below

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr>gcovr -v -r .
Filters for --root: (1)
- <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x01C206A0>
Filters for --filter: (1)
- DirectoryPrefixFilter(C\:\/Users\/user\/Desktop\/Gcovr\/)
Filters for --exclude: (0)
Filters for --gcov-filter: (1)
- AlwaysMatchFilter()
Filters for --gcov-exclude: (0)
Filters for --exclude-directories: (0)
Scanning directory . for gcda/gcno files...
Found 4 files (and will process 2)
Pool started with 1 threads
Processing file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.gcda --branch-counts -- 
branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr' in 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyekiry'
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.gcda --branch-counts -- 
branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr'
Finding source file corresponding to a gcov data file
  currdir      C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr
  gcov_fname   c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyekiry\main.cpp.gcov
           [u'        -', u'    0', u'Source', u'main.cpp\n']
  source_fname C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.gcda
  root         C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr
  fname        C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.cpp
Parsing coverage data for file C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.cpp
uncovered: set([])
covered:   {2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 4}
branches:  {5: {1: 1, 2: 0}, 6: {1: 1, 2: 0}, 7: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0}}
noncode:   set([3])
Finding source file corresponding to a gcov data file
  currdir      C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr
  gcov_fnamec:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyekiry\c~#mingw#lib#gcc#mingw32#6.3.0#include#c++#iostream.gcov
           [u'        -', u'    0', u'Source', 
u'c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/iostream\n']
  source_fname C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\main.gcda
  root         C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr
  fname        c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream
Parsing coverage data for file c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream
  Filtering coverage data for file c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream
Processing file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\math.gcda
Running gcov: 'gcov C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr\math.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gcovr' in 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyekiry'
Gathered coveraged data for 1 files
```

Comment: Can you share your main.cpp code?

Comment: Hmm, this is unusual. Just to check: (1) you ran the `math` executable and (2) this created a `math.gcda` file next to the executable? If the problem persists, could you perhaps post the output of running gcovr in `--verbose` mode? This may indicate why the other files are not shown. It would also be useful to know which gcovr version you are using, the current release is version 4.1.

Comment: Hi, I am using gcovr version 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are explicitly passing the header file `math.hpp` to the compiler. This does not contain any definitions that would produce object code, which leads to the following sequence of events:

1. `main.cpp` is compiled. A file `main.gcno` is created that allows the coverage data `main.gcda` to be interpreted by gcov.
2. `math.cpp` is compiled which creates a `math.gcno` file.
3. `math.hpp` is compiled which overwrites `math.gcno` with an *empty* file.

Therefore, no coverage data for math.cpp is recognized, and the file is excluded from coverage.

It is not necessary to pass `math.hpp` to the compiler since your source files `#include` this file. If we remove the header from the compiler invocation, we get the following gcovr output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.cpp                                       4       4   100%   
math.cpp                                       9       9   100%   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                         13      13   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(The math.hpp file is still not listed, but it contains zero statements that could be covered.)